# the average of optical flow

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I want to find the average of the optical flow, I could extract the features from the first frame and found their location in the next frame. Now, I want to find the average of the displacement in order to translate the image back to its stationary background in order to stabilize the image.

```
// here I take the optical flow 
cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK(frame1_1C, frame2_1C, pyramid1, pyramid2, frame1_features,
                       frame2_features, corner_count, optical_flow_window, 5,
                       optical_flow_found_feature, NULL,
                       optical_flow_termination_criteria, NULL);

// here the features that I extract them 
for( int i=0; i < corner_count; i++ ) {
  CvPoint p,q;
  if ( optical_flow_found_feature[i] == 0 ) continue;
  p.x = (int) frame1_features[i].x;
  p.y = (int) frame1_features[i].y;
  q.x = (int) frame2_features[i].x;
  q.y = (int) frame2_features[i].y;

  double angle = atan2( (double) p.y - q.y, (double) p.x - q.x );
  double hypotenuse = sqrt( square(p.y - q.y) + square(p.x - q.x) );
```

Now I want to take the average for them, and if you want me to show you more of the code I'm ready to do that.

The corner_count is the number of the features.

Comment: I suggest that you (a) ask a question -- all you do right now is tell us what you want to do and we're guessing about what you are having trouble with, (b) format your code as code -- refer to the icons above the text box in which you create / edit your question, (c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming from what you have written that you want to find the average displacement of all the feature points between the two frames.  In that case all you have to do is compute the "hypotenuse" in a loop over the features, add up all its values, and then divide by the number of features.

Ok, here's your answer:

```
cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK(frame1_1C, frame2_1C, pyramid1, pyramid2, frame1_features, frame2_features, corner_count, optical_flow_window, 5, optical_flow_found_feature, NULL, optical_flow_termination_criteria, NULL);
//here the features that I extract them 

double sumOfDistances = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < corner_count; ++i)
{
   int x1 = (int) frame1_features[i].x;    
   int y1 = (int) frame1_features[i].y;
   int x2 = (int) frame2_features[i].x;  
   int y2 = (int) frame2_features[i].y;

   int dx = x2 - x1;
   int dy = y2 - y1;
   sumOfDistances += sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
double averageDistance = sumOfDistances / corner_count;
```

I am assuming here that `corner_count` is the number of features.  You would need to make sure that is indeed correct.  Also, I haven't tried to compile this.  If I had made any mistakes, it would be up to you to fix them.

However, if you are planning to do image processing more than just this one time, I suggest that you actually learn some programming.  What I did here is very basic stuff.  Without understanding this for yourself you will not get very far.

Comment: @Dima, Yeah that's totally right, that what I was looking for, could you be more specific with my code cause I'm not a good programmer. Thank you so much for your feed back.

Comment: @Dima, is there anyway to contact with you to show you my code, I know how program and these stuff but im not so good.

Comment: Look, I mean no disrespect, and I don't mean to be rude, but if you don't know how to write code to compute an average of a set of numbers, then you don't know how to program.  At the very least, you don't know how to program in C++.  Sorry, but I don't have the time to debug your code for you, and I also don't believe it will help you in the long run.  You need to get a book on C++ and learn the basics, so that you actually understand what every line of your code means.  Otherwise, it won't help you if somebody else fixes your code.  I am sorry, if my words seem harsh, but this is the truth.

Comment: @Dima, I know how to do it but what I wanted was to see if I'm doing right or not? I could run my code and I know to compute the average and what you have done to me I could do it. but my problem is how to get translate the second frame features to its original place.

Comment: @Dima, I'm a master student in Robotics and intelligent systems but my background was in Electronic engineering so I'm struggling with programming, that's why I want someone just to see that what I'm doing is right?

Comment: Then you probably need to compute not the average distance by which the points have moved, but the average displacement in x and the average displacement in y.  In other words you would need the average of (x2 - x1) and the average of (y2 - y1), not the average of the hypotenuse.  Then you can subtract the average x displacement from the x coordinate, and the average y displacement from the y coordinate of the feature.  But still, if you are working in robotics and doing computer vision, you have to learn programming.  And you have to start from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. That's right to start over studying programming. I know how to deal with errors and debugging but NOT much about the basics.