# What exactly is the output when we run the dense optical flow (farnnback)?

Tags: opencv, opticalflow

I have been running the Python implementation code of Dense Optical Flow given in the official documentation page. At one particular line of the code, they use
mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(flow[...,0], flow[...,1]).
When I print the values of mag, I get these - 
[Please check this image for the output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxL1R.png)

I have no idea how to make sense of this output.

My end objective is to use optical flow to get a resultant or an average motion value for every frame.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the same OpenCV tutorial you use

> We get a 2-channel array with optical flow vectors, (u,v).

That is the output of the dense optical flow. Basically it tells you how each of the points moved in a vectorial way. `(u,v)` is just the cartesian representation of a vector and it can be converted to polar coordinates, this means an angle and the magnitude.

The angle is the orientation where the pixel moved. And the magnitude is the distance that the pixel moved.

In many algorithms you may use the magnitude to know if the pixel moved (less than 1 means no movement for example). Or if you are tracking an object which you know the initial position (meaning the pixels position of the object) you may find where the majority of the pixels are moving to, and use that info to determine the new position.

BTW, cartToPolar returns the angles in Radians unless it is specified. Here is an extract of the documentation:

```
cv2.cartToPolar(x, y[, magnitude[, angle[, angleInDegrees]]]) → magnitude, angle
```

`angleInDegrees` must be `True` if you need it in degrees.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for your insights. I was wondering is there a way I can find the average motion throughout the video? Like say a frame number 199 has a total motion of some 14.035, similarly is there a way I can get frames and the total average motion value in that frame spanning over the whole video?

Comment: @AdaMStrange to calculate the motion you need a reference frame and a new frame, if you do it for frame 199, you need to select a reference frame... maybe frame 1 or frame 198. Then you can average the magnitudes and say the average movement in this frame with respect to the reference. The same would it be in the video, you have to define what is your reference frame and get the pixel motion. It is important to note that if the two images are totally different (e.g. change of scene), you may get undesirable results. To get frames of a video use VideoCapture from OpenCV

Comment: @AdaMStrange one more thing, this methods are quite slow, if it is only a section of the image, crop it first or maybe use the sparse methods.

Comment: I tried using the sparse methods like LK for example. And i referred to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117914/the-average-of-optical-flow for finding the average.But when i take the difference between the frames, the difference is almost zero.